# A template matching issue

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a source html looks like:

```
<p class="heading-8">Emergency Care<span class="char-style-override-68">, if not already done:</span></p>
<p class="List-Bullet-CHAM1-CHAM-1-List-Bullet-1 para-style-override-3"><span>  </span><span class="char-style-override-25">1.</span><span> Do Initial Assessment (p. 72).</span></p>
```

Now I create a template match for p:

```
<xsl:template match="x:p">
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="contains(@class,'heading-8')">
   <xsl:variable name="current-name" select="generate-id(.)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="noTable" select="count(preceding-sibling::x:table)"/>
   <p>
    <b>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
   </p>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::x:p][contains(@class,'List-Bullet-CHAM1-CHAM-1')][generate-id(preceding-sibling::x:p[contains(@class,'heading-8 ')][1]) = $current-name]">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::x:p[contains(@class,'List-Bullet-CHAM1-CHAM-1')][count(preceding-sibling::x:table)=$noTable][generate-id(preceding-sibling::x:p[contains(@class,'heading-8 ')][1]) = $current-name]" mode="bullet"/>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
 </xsl:when>
```

The issue I am having now is that it seems that I could never get in to that inner if branch. But I think the source html matches perfectly with it, just don't know where I could be wrong.

PS, I used generate-id() function to determine the identity of a preceding sibling node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the test condition of the xsl:if statement looks fine, except the trailing space in `contains(@class,'heading-8 ')`. There's no *class* attribute that contains the string "heading-8 ". Removing the space in both the xsl:if and xsl:apply-templates elements should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-complicating the **if** condition. It looks like you are checking if the following sibling is a **p** tag, and is has a specific **class** attribute. Because you are already postioned on a **p** element with a class of 'heading-8', you probably don't need to worry about the generate-id(), and can just simplify it to the following:

```
<xsl:if 
   test="following-sibling::*[1][self::x:p][contains(@class,'List-Bullet-CHAM1-CHAM-1')]">
```